# Focus next input once reaching maxlength value - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```js
function focusNext() {
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.productKey');

  const card = Array.from(cards);

  card.forEach(card => {
    const lenMax = card.attributes["maxlength"].value;
    console.log(lenMax);
    if (card.value.length === lenMax) {
      card.nextSibling.nextSibling.focus();
      console.log('Success');
    } else {
      console.log('error');

    }
  });
}
focusNext();
```

```html
<input name="productkey" class="productKey" type="text" id="productkey1" value="" size="4" maxlength="4" />-<input name="productkey" class="productKey" type="text" id="productkey2" value="" size="4" maxlength="4" />-<input name="productkey" class="productKey"
  type="text" id="productkey3" value="" size="4" maxlength="4" />-<input name="productkey" class="productKey" type="text" id="productkey4" value="" size="4" maxlength="4" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have change the code little bit. May this helps you!

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


    <input name="productkey" class="productKey" type="text" id="productkey1" value="" size="4" maxlength="4" />-<input name="productkey" class="productKey" type="text" id="productkey2" value="" size="4" maxlength="4" />-<input name="productkey" class="productKey"
  type="text" id="productkey3" value="" size="4" maxlength="4" />-<input name="productkey" class="productKey" type="text" id="productkey4" value="" size="4" maxlength="4" />
 Run code snippet

 <script>



function focusNext() {
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.productKey');

    for (let index = 0; index < cards.length; index++) {
        const card = cards[index];
        card.addEventListener("input", function() {
            if(this.value.length === 4) {
                this.nextSibling.nextSibling.focus();
            }
        });    
    }
}
focusNext();

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```